# Skype doesn't show notifications

Tags: windows-7, skype, notifications

Suddenly, my Skype (ver: 5.0.0.105) doesn't show notifications when other someone starts a chat with me although I've set configuration to do that. This make me lose some important conversations. I've tried a lot to fix it, but many tries with Google doesn't help much.

Any ideas/suggestions on how to fix it?
[image: my Skype config]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://jira.skype.com/browse/SCW-2831) with Skype, that if your taskbar is set to "autohide", Skype will not display notifications.